# Flutter Google ML kit face detection InputImage Error

Tags: flutter, face-detection, google-mlkit

I am trying to make a face detection project with Flutter. But I could not solve this error:

> Flutter google ml kit face detection InputImage width and height should be at least 32!, null, null

Errors:

> I/flutter ( 6727): Error processing image: PlatformException(FaceDetectorError, com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: InputImage width and height should be at least 32!, null, null)
>
> I/flutter ( 6727): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
>
> I/flutter ( 6727): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
>
> I/flutter ( 6727):
>
> I/flutter ( 6727): #2      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:485:35)

It's about this part:

```
Future<void> startFaceDetection() async {
await _cameraController!.startImageStream((CameraImage image) async {
  final sensorOrientation =
      _cameraController!.description.sensorOrientation;
  final rotationIndex =
      sensorOrientation % InputImageRotation.values.length;
  final rotation = InputImageRotation.values[rotationIndex];

  final inputImageMetadata = InputImageMetadata(
    size: Size((image.planes[0].height ?? 0).toDouble(),
        (image.planes[0].width ?? 0).toDouble()),
    rotation: rotation,
    format: InputImageFormat.nv21,
    bytesPerRow: image.planes[0].bytesPerRow,
  );

  if (inputImageMetadata.format != InputImageFormat.nv21) {
    print('Error: The ByteBuffer is not in the declared format.');
    return;
  }

  if (inputImageMetadata.size !=
      Size((image.planes[0].height ?? 0).toDouble(),
          (image.planes[0].width ?? 0).toDouble())) {
    print(
        'Error: The image dimensions have been changed after the ByteBuffer was created.');
    return;
  }

  final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
    bytes: image.planes[0].bytes,
    metadata: inputImageMetadata,
  );

  try {
    final List<Face> faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);

    for (Face face in faces) {
      final boundingBox = face.boundingBox;
      final headEulerAngleY = face.headEulerAngleY;
      final headEulerAngleZ = face.headEulerAngleZ;
    }
  } catch (e, stackTrace) {
    print('Error processing image: $e\n$stackTrace');
  }
});
}
```

All of the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CameraController? _cameraController;
  List<CameraDescription>? _cameras;
  int _selectedCameraIndex = 0;
  late FaceDetector _faceDetector;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeCamera();
  }

  Future<void> initializeCamera() async {
    _cameras = await availableCameras();
    if (_cameras == null || _cameras!.isEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Kamera Hatası'),
            content: Text('Cihazınızda bir kamera bulunmuyor.'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('Tamam'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      return;
    } else {
      final selectedCamera = _cameras![_selectedCameraIndex];
      _cameraController = CameraController(
        selectedCamera,
        ResolutionPreset.medium,
      );
      await _cameraController!.initialize();

      _faceDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector();

      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        startFaceDetection();
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> startFaceDetection() async {
    await _cameraController!.startImageStream((CameraImage image) async {
      final sensorOrientation =
          _cameraController!.description.sensorOrientation;
      final rotationIndex =
          sensorOrientation % InputImageRotation.values.length;
      final rotation = InputImageRotation.values[rotationIndex];

      final inputImageMetadata = InputImageMetadata(
        size: Size((image.planes[0].height ?? 0).toDouble(),
            (image.planes[0].width ?? 0).toDouble()),
        rotation: rotation,
        format: InputImageFormat.nv21,
        bytesPerRow: image.planes[0].bytesPerRow,
      );

      if (inputImageMetadata.format != InputImageFormat.nv21) {
        print('Error: The ByteBuffer is not in the declared format.');
        return;
      }

      if (inputImageMetadata.size !=
          Size((image.planes[0].height ?? 0).toDouble(),
              (image.planes[0].width ?? 0).toDouble())) {
        print(
            'Error: The image dimensions have been changed after the ByteBuffer was created.');
        return;
      }

      final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
        bytes: image.planes[0].bytes,
        metadata: inputImageMetadata,
      );

      try {
        final List<Face> faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);

        for (Face face in faces) {
          final boundingBox = face.boundingBox;
          final headEulerAngleY = face.headEulerAngleY;
          final headEulerAngleZ = face.headEulerAngleZ;
        }
      } catch (e, stackTrace) {
        print('Error processing image: $e\n$stackTrace');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController?.dispose();
    _faceDetector.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void toggleCamera() {
    setState(() {
      _selectedCameraIndex = (_selectedCameraIndex + 1) % _cameras!.length;
      final selectedCamera = _cameras![_selectedCameraIndex];
      _cameraController =
          CameraController(selectedCamera, ResolutionPreset.high);
      _cameraController!.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {
          startFaceDetection();
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kamera'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _cameraController?.value.isInitialized == true
                ? AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 32 / 32,
                    child: CameraPreview(_cameraController!),
                  )
                : Lottie.asset('Assets/face_loading_4.json'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            isExtended: true,
            onPressed: toggleCamera,
            tooltip: 'Kamera Değiştir',
            child: Icon(Icons.switch_camera),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What dimensions does the input image have?

Comment: @halfer
input; 
print(
          'Giriş resmi boyutları: ${image.planes[0].height} x ${image.planes[0].width}');
output;
I/flutter (32086): Giriş resmi boyutları: null x null

how can i fix it?

Comment: What do you have in `image.planes.length`? See if this array does indeed have an image in it. Also, can you check what format the image is and whether it is acceptable to the image loader here?

Comment: @halfer image.planes.length = 3
image.planes=  [Instance of 'Plane', Instance of 'Plane', Instance of 'Plane']
The image format should be written as nv21 in the google ml kit documents for android.
It seems that size information cannot be accessed during image variable processing.

Comment: OK. I don't know this tech, but perhaps the size verification error is bumping into the restriction you mention. Have you searched for this error to see if others have encountered it?

Comment: @halfer yes I couldn't find the solution to this error